# Is there a limit size of malloc?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have a problem when I try to run my cuda program in TITAN BLACK which something like this (i simplified it so it doesn't looks complicated)

```
    int DIMX, DIMZ,DIMXM, DIMZM;

    DIMXM=5700;
    DIMZM=5700;

    DIMX=DIMXM+20;
    DIMZ=DIMZM+10;

    float *temptxz = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ));    
    float *temptxx = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ));        
    float *temptzz = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ));        
    float *tempvz = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ)); 
    float *tempvx = (float*)malloc( sizeof(float)*(DIMX*DIMZ));

    for (int ij=0; ij<DIMX*DIMZ; ij++)
    {
    temptxz[ij]=0.0;                
    temptxx[ij]=0.0;
    temptzz[ij]=0.0;
    tempvx[ij]=0.0;
    tempvz[ij]=0.0;
    }
```

it is ok for NX=4700; NZ=4700; but if I increase it a little more (making the memory size above 2 gb), the compiling went fine, but when i run the program it crashed and the warning is "0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

is that beacause there is some kind of limitation size in malloc?
or something about pitch memory that said in TITAN black it's only 2 GB?

sorry for my awful english. Thanks

Comment: http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/

Comment: No, it is due to some kind of OS limitation of the memory available to a single process.

Comment: Is the code you have shown here device code or host code?  Based on the warning message you have posted it would appear to be host code.  If that is the case, are you running on a 32bit or 64bit OS?  How much memory is in your system (not GPU memory, host memory)?

Comment: I imagine the maximum value that a `size_t` can hold would be the absolute maximum.

Comment: i am using 64 bit windows 32 gb ram. So is there any solution for this?

Comment: I modified my answer with an answer specific to CUDA in how to increase malloc size.  By default you're dealing with 8MB.  I'm not sure if you can scale it up as large as 2gb, but it's worth a try.

Comment: My best guess is you are compiling a win32 app in windows.  In that case, see Greg Smith's answer below.  Switch to an x64 project instead, if you are compiling in Visual Studio.  You may not be able to do this easily if you are using Visual Studio Express edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On windows a 32-bit process has 2GB user VA space limit by default. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN page for limits on different windows OS versions and options to potentially increase the limits. The best solution is to compile the application as a 64-bit application which has a 8TB user space VA limit.

Answer (score 5):

Check your pointers once you've malloced.  Malloc ATTEMPTS to make room on the heap for a variable, but it can't guarantee the variable is made.  This would usually be due to a memory limit imposed by your environment.  You can always check to see if a pointer is created properly by checking the value after you malloc.

```
x = malloc(SIZE);
if(x == NULL) //error
```

This validation is always important, because otherwise you'll be attempting to write to a memory address that doesn't exist (0x0)

For CUDA specifically, you can set the heap size explicitly using

```
cudaDeviceSetLimit()
```

It's in the [documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7.html).

Comment: It turns out I forgot to change "the target to x64 machine" option on the compiler. Thanks.

Comment: If that was the solution that worked for you, please mark the OTHER answer as correct, as that is the one that directly suggested the target platform.  (It seems you have now done this!  Glad you got your issue resolved)